# Getting exception while attempting to delete the COM dll file after unloading an AppDomain

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, appdomain, appdomainsetup

Getting exception while attempting to delete the COM dll file after unloading an AppDomain.
Exception detail:  Failed to apply auto update
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'IQVdxp32.dll' is denied.
Code:

```
private bool ApplyUpdate(string tempfolderpath)
    {
        bool result;
        try
        {
            Destroy();
            if (Directory.Exists(moduledir))
                Directory.Delete(moduledir, true); /*Getting excpetion while deleting that unload appdomain directory*/
            DirectoryUtils.Copy(tempfolderpath, moduledir);
            Create();
            log.Info("Auto update successful for module : " + modulename);
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            log.Error("Failed to apply auto update", exception);
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
 public void Destroy()
    {
        if (appdomain != null)
        {
            lock (objappdomainlocker)
            {
                if (appdomain != null)
                {
                    CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx(10000, (UInt32)0);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)10000);
                    if (loader != null && apolomain != null)
                    {
                        loader.CallInternalOnObject("Destroy", null, apolomain);
                    }
                    // unload the AppDomain completely
                    AppDomain.Unload(appdomain);
                    appdomain = null;
                    loader = null;
                    apolomain = null;
                    IsPersist = false;
                 }
            }
        }
    }

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern void CoFreeUnusedLibrariesEx(UInt32 unloadDelay, UInt32 reserved);
```

Comment: COM servers don't know anything about AppDomains.   Their scope is process-wide.  So you might have destroyed the RCWs but the DLL is still loaded.  That keeps a lock on the file.  You'd have to at least pinvoke CoFreeUnusedLibraries(), might work.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant - Will you mind to provide some sample code or link in order to use CoFreeUnusedLibraries(). Thanks.

Comment: There is no code, it is merely [a DllImport declaration](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/CoFreeUnusedLibraries.html).

Comment: @HansPassant i have tried above code by putting CoFreeUnusedLibraries(), but i am getting the same exception, do you think i am missing anything?

Comment: First Unload, then GC.Collect, then CoFreeUnusedLibraries might work.

Comment: @HansPassant Still not working. Do you know any other way to handle this exception?

Comment: Renaming the file before trying to overwrite it is another workaround.  Murky if using the DLL again will now provide the updated version.  But really rather best to just not do this, it is too brittle.  Updating DLLs should be done by stopping the program first.  I know, kicked in an open door.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant - I think renaming is not correct process as well as i can't stop the program before updating DLLs. Do you have another solution?

Comment: Try deleting it in the `AppDomain.DomainUnload` Event. It seems to be related to COM object not freed up properly; There might still be a reference to the COM object present in the code.